# How to run Kotlin on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kotlin

I just installed Kotlin on Ubuntu with the commands below,

```
curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
sdk install kotlin
```

And it's installed with the lines below,

```
Downloading: kotlin 1.3.61

In progress...

######################################################################################################## 100.0%

Installing: kotlin 1.3.61
Done installing!
*************************************************************
```

But when I try to execute a file, it doesn't work.

```
comp@ubuntu:~$ kotlin --version
/home/comp/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin/kotlinc: line 80: java: command not found

comp@ubuntu:~$ chmod +x test.kt 
comp@ubuntu:~$ kotlinc test.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
/home/comp/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin/kotlinc: line 80: java: command not found

comp@ubuntu:~$ which kotlinc
/home/comp/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin/kotlinc
```

Line 80 of the file "/home/comp/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin/kotlinc" is below,

```
"${JAVACMD:=java}" $JAVA_OPTS "${java_args[@]}" -cp "${kotlin_app[@]}" "${kotlin_args[@]}"
```

What can be the problem? Problems with some Java components? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you will also need to install java - try this:

```
apt install default-jre
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [snap](https://snapcraft.io/docs) to easily install packages and all its dependencies:

```
sudo snap install --classic kotlin
```

Now compile using Kotlin compiler `kotlinc`:

```
kotlinc test.kt -include-runtime -d test.jar
```

The `-d` option indicates the output path for generated class files which may be either a directory or a .jar file. The `-include-runtime` option makes the resulting .jar file self-contained and runnable by including the Kotlin runtime library in it.

Now run the application:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

For any help use:

```
kotlinc -help
```

For version info:

```
kotlin -version
```